# Scroll problem with mouse and my tablet android

Tags: usb, mouse

I  have a [HUAWEI MediaPad M5 Lite 10 tablet](https://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B07G3JFHJR/?tag=hu2-21) I use it with a mouse connected to USB thanks to [this adapter](https://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B07YWW8C6X/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1).

For some time with my mouse, I can no longer scroll through the pages of browsers like Firefox or Chrome.

Rather than scrolling the text from top to bottom or vice versa, it selects the text for me!

I can no longer also do a copy / paste in the web pages, it selects but without displaying "copy / paste" I reset my tablet but it doesn't change anything.

I have tried with a bluetooth mouse and have the same problem.

The funny thing is that when I take control of my tablet with my computer and with teamviewer I use my computer mouse! Well it works.

I can scroll web pages through my computer. An idea ? Thank you

Comment: To encourage people to answer your question, they first need to read it all.  I encourage you to make your post more readable.  For starters, you may want to familiarize yourself with the benefits of using paragraphs.

Comment: I'm relaunching the subject because I'm not no answer